# MySQL require a minimum length

Tags: mysql, sql, check-constraints

I'm using MySQL Workbench and I made a table called 'organizations' and want to block any try of adding a value to a column with less than 5 letters.
The column name is 'namee'.
I made this, but I get an error:

```
ALTER TABLE organizations
ADD CONSTRAINT MINIMO CHECK (LENGTH(namee) >= 5);
```

Error:

```
Error Code: 3814. An expression of a check constraint 'MINIMO' contains disallowed function: `LEN`.
```

Comment: You can build the logic into the insert itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message you shared, you apparently tried to use a function `LEN()`. No built-in function of that name exists in MySQL.

Testing with MySQL 8.0.21, I can reproduce the error you showed if I try using `LEN()` or any other nonexistent function.

```
mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.21    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE organizations ADD CONSTRAINT MINIMO CHECK (LEN(namee) >= 5);
ERROR 3814 (HY000): An expression of a check constraint 'MINIMO' contains disallowed function: `LEN`.

mysql> ALTER TABLE organizations ADD CONSTRAINT MINIMO CHECK (BOGUS(namee) >= 5);
ERROR 3814 (HY000): An expression of a check constraint 'MINIMO' contains disallowed function: `BOGUS`.
```

If you had tried to define a stored function called `LEN()` and use that, you should read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html:

> Stored functions and user-defined functions are not permitted.

But `LENGTH()` works without error. By the way, I'd recommend to use `CHAR_LENGTH()` so multibyte characters are counted as one character.

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE organizations ADD CONSTRAINT MINIMO CHECK (CHAR_LENGTH(namee) >= 5);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

That seems odd.  Does this work?

```
ALTER TABLE organizations
    ADD CONSTRAINT MINIMO CHECK (LENGTH(namee) LIKE '_____');
```

I suspect that `LENGTH()` is non-deterministic; I am not sure why this would be.

Answer (score 0):

At least in older versions, and you didn't specify which version, a trigger is needed for checking length.

```
CREATE TRIGGER t1 BEFORE INSERT ON organizations
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

   DECLARE numLength INT;
   SET numLength = (SELECT LENGTH(NEW. namee));

   IF (numLength > 30) THEN
     SET NEW.col = 1/0;
   END IF;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table (my_string VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);

SET @string = 'red';

INSERT INTO my_table SELECT @string FROM (SELECT 1)x WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(@string) >= 5;

SET @string = 'orange';

INSERT INTO my_table SELECT @string FROM (SELECT 1)x WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(@string) >= 5;

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+-----------+
| my_string |
+-----------+
| orange    |
+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which version you are using but it works fine for me on MYSQL 8.x

```
create table test_check(name varchar(10));

ALTER TABLE test_check
ADD CONSTRAINT MINIMO CHECK (LENGTH(name) >= 5);
```